# pythonanywhere flask how to start programing?

Tags: python, flask

From the tab Files,  `mysite/`, `flask_app.py`. I change this program, save it, and Reload my web, 
But what I change to print on the `flask_app.py` is not response on the web page. It's still the same as I have never edited this file.

Comment: Did you restart the server, too? It’s not reexecuted on every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here.  That certainly should work, so long as you're hitting the "Reload" button on the "Web" tab.  What's your PythonAnywhere username?